# how to avoid my the keyboard from moving up my footer

Tags: react-native

hey There i am working with a react native app and i have a footer that i am who made but when i use the keayboard that footer move up above the keyboard and above my flatlist i tried things like  but its not working and i cant change android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" because i have other behavior in thesame app

here is my code

```
 render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {!this.state.search ? (
          <Header/>
        ) : (
          <SearchabalHeader/>
        )}
        <View style={styles.listContainer}>
          <FlatList
            data={this.state.data}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
              return (
                <Item
                  status={item.status}
                  price={item.price}
                  address={item.address}
                  dateTime={new Date()}
                />
              );
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.footerContainer}>
          <Footer activeTab="tab-2" user={this.props.user} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and my style is

```
StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: colors.grey_Three,
    flex: 1,
  },
  listContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: '3%',
    paddingTop: '2%',
  },
  footerContainer: {},
});
```

Comment: can u share a snack OR image/gif ?

Comment: Did you try KeyboardAvoidingView in react native?

Comment: thank u guys i fix theproblemby addinga listner to the keyboard then hide or show the footer